# Codebehind does not create button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I have created a ASP.NET Empty Website in a new install of Visual Studio 2017 Community.  I am attempting to replicate the steps shown by the following tutorial: https://youtu.be/5dCAXwhjIYU

I'm simply planting three text boxes on the form, along with a submit button.  When i double click the button, The IDE simply highlights the HTML for the button in the source view of the page.  It does not create the event handler in the code-behind as shown in the video and as expected.

I manually created the event handler for the button click in the code behind. When I try to run the code, it is telling me that the fields I'm referencing do not exist:

> Error  CS0103  The name 'UserName' does not exist in the current context

Here's my HTML code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Users.aspx.cs" Inherits="Users" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            UserName<br />
            <input id="UserName" type="text" /><br />
            UserEmail<br />
            <input id="UserEmail" type="text" /><br />
            UserCampus<br />
            <input id="UserCampus" type="text" /><br />
            <input id="SaveUser" type="submit" value="submit" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The C# code:

```
public partial class Users : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void SaveUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection BIGateConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;Integrated Security=True");
        {
            SqlCommand BIGateSQLCmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [BIGateway].[dbo].[User] (UserName, userEmail, userCampus) VALUES (@userName, @userEmail, @userCampus)", BIGateConnection);
            BIGateSQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", UserName.Text);
            BIGateSQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", UserEmail.Text);
            BIGateSQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", UserCampus.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line of code is being cited in the error message as the cause of the error?

Comment: I'm getting an error on each of the following lines:              
     BIGateSQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", UserName.Text);
            BIGateSQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", UserEmail.Text);
            BIGateSQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", UserCampus.Text);

Specifically, it is complaining about the text box items UserName, UserEmail and UserCampus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have taken HTML text box then code is as follows:

```
<input id="UserName" type="text" /><br />
```

In this you will have to add the line on your own as runat="server"

It will look as follows:

```
<input id="UserName" type="text"  runat="server"/><br />
```

Then you can use it for serverside.

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Why wouldn't the `input` tags inherit the runat setting from the `form` tag?

Comment: The runat="server" attribute indicates that the form should be processed on the server. It also indicates that the enclosed controls can be accessed by server scripts:

Comment: Yes, I know what the tag does.  I'm asking why `<input id="UserName" type="text">` isn't already `runat="server"` by virtue of it being contained within the `<form id="form1" runat="server">` tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's just how ASP works.  You'll have to ask them why they designed their controls that way.  Do note however that for just about any ASP application your entire page will virtually always be in a server form, so you're proposing every single HTML element (in a practical sense) should have `runat=server`, which is more or less the same as just omitting it entirely and just assuming all elements should be server elements.

Comment: I'm glad I don't do ASP.NET anymore (I switched to ASP.NET MVC a long time ago and never looked back).

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Adding the code runat="server" solved the errors.  I'm still not getting the codebehind with a doubleclick on the button.  But that is a very minor issue.

Answer (score 1):

Video doesn't show the ASPX page. I believe he used ***TextBox*** and ***Button*** server controls.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        UserName<br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName"/><br />
        UserEmail<br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserEmail"/><br />
        UserCampus<br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserCampus"/><br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SaveUser" OnClick="SaveUser_Click" Text="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

If he used regular html `input` with `runat="server"`, he will have to access the value as `UserName.Value` inside `Button1_Click` event which he did not.

Answer (score 0):

Afais you didn't find the click event to the button.
Add

```
SaveUser.OnClick += SaveUser_Click;
```

To the page_load event.

In general I would prefer asp:Button instead of input.
In fact it's rendered as a input control. But with more options. But indeed runat="server" is missing for the input.